# Why does integration by parts yield $0=1$ here?

Tags: fake-proofs

I tried doing integration by parts on this integral:
$$I = \int \frac{1}{x\log{x}}dx$$
With these substitutions:
$$u = \frac{1}{\log{x}} \rightarrow du = -\frac{1}{x\log^2{x}}$$
$$dv = \frac{1}{x}dx \rightarrow v=\log{x}$$

We get:
$$\begin{align}
I &= uv - \int vdu \\
I &= \log{x}\frac{1}{\log{x}} - \int \log{x}(-\frac{1}{x\log^2x})dx \\
I &= 1 + \int \frac{1}{x\log{x}}dx\\
I &= 1 + I\\
0 &= 1
\end{align}
$$
How does this happen?

Comment: This is one of the reasons that we tell people to put "$+C$"s everywhere.

Comment: Your substitution with $u= \frac 1{log(x)} $works fine  you evalutae $I=-\int \frac {du} u $ no need here for integration by part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compare *indefinite* integrals you should expect that they can differ by a constant term -- the constant of integration.

In particular, when you subtract "the same" indefinite integral in the last line, there should be a $C_2-C_1$ left on one of the sides.

Answer (score 2):

Note:
$$\int \frac{1}{x\ln{x}}dx=\int \frac{1}{\ln{x}}d(\ln{x})=\ln{\ln{x}}+C_1=\ln{\ln{x}}+C_2+1.$$